# JQuery ui how to make certain elements in a selectable not selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a list of JQuery ui selectable elements called "#selectable" and there are some elements inside the selectable that I no not want to be selectable, I want them there as list dividers.

Here is an example of what the list looks like:

```
<ol>
    <li class='custType'>This is a divider</li>
    <li class='ui-widget-content'>This is selectable</li>
    <li class='ui-widget-content'>This is selectable</li>
    <li class='ui-widget-content'>This is selectable</li>
    <li class='custType'>This is a divider</li>
    <li class='ui-widget-content'>This is selectable</li>
    <li class='ui-widget-content'>This is selectable</li>
</ol>
```

The ones that have the class "custType" are dividers and I no not want them to be selectable, it just divides the list up into categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [filter](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-filter) option to only select those items that should be selectable:

```
$( ".selector" ).selectable({ filter: "li" });
```

In your case:

```
$( "ol" ).selectable({ filter: "li.ui-widget-content" });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NDMYL/)**